# How can I add a border to the label for checkboxes when they are selected?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set up a word guessing game, and I want the user to have multiple 'word banks' to choose from. I'm using checkboxes, wrapped in labels, for the selections. I want to put a border around the label element when the checkbox is checked because ideally, I want the actual checkbox hidden/not showing.

I've tried adding a border to the button only while checked using :checked, but that did not work. I also tried looking for solutions online but most solutions I was able to dig up were only adding styling to the actual box, not the label, and I want the border around the whole label so that I can hide the checkboxes but still indicate which 'bank' is selected.

```
<form id="wordBanks">
    <label for="perksCheck">Perks<input type="checkbox" id="perksCheck" selected></label>
    <label for="equipmentCheck">Euipment<input type="checkbox" id="equipmentCheck"></label>
</form>
```

I'd paste my CSS, too, but since the code I have doesn't work I'll leave it out. Can provide on request if you want, though.

Comment: The child node can't access the parent, but if they are siblings you can. Make label and input siblings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than wrapping the checkbox inside the label you could do something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="perksCheck" checked>
<label for="perksCheck">Perks</label>
```

In your CSS, you can then target the label if the checkbox above it has been checked by using an [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator).

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

My go to solution is usually to wrap the label in a span, and place the checkbox before the label.

```
<form id="wordBanks">
         <span><input type="checkbox" id="perksCheck" checked><label for="perksCheck">Perks</label></span>
         <span><input type="checkbox" id="equipmentCheck"><label for="equipmentCheck">Euipment</label></span>   
</form>
```

You can possibly even avoid wrapping it into a span, but I find it easier to reason about when you have several attributes (e.g start throwing in accessibility attributes and your element will wrap on a new line on most screens).

This example doesn't lose any functionality an you can style the label with:

```
    input[type=checkbox]:checked + label
```

Sidenote: A checkbox is "checked" not "selected".

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to wrap the input inside the label.

**Highlighting adjacent label only**

If you want to highlight the `<label>` and do not want to use JS then you have to change the order of the elements. Take `<input>' first and`` later. Because in CSS when we use

`input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label` it expect the `<label>` to be its next element aka Sibling of the input.

Here is what you can try

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<form id="wordBanks">
  <input type="checkbox" id="perksCheck" selected> 
  <label for="perksCheck">Perks </label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="equipmentCheck">
  <label for="equipmentCheck">Euipment</label>
</form>
```

**Highlighting Checkbox only**

If the goal is to highlight the checkbox then you can add `box-shadow` to it.

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px black;
}
```

```html
<form id="wordBanks">
  <label for="perksCheck">Perks<input type="checkbox" id="perksCheck" selected></label>
  <label for="equipmentCheck">Euipment<input type="checkbox" id="equipmentCheck"></label>
</form>
```

Read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked